# Grails dependency injection no longer working after upgrade to Grails 1.3.3

Tags: spring, grails, flex3, dependency-injection, blazeds

Project setup is Flex 3-BlazeDS-Spring Flex Integration-Grails

Dependency injection in my Service classes was working just fine with Grails 1.2.1, when service methods were called from my flex client.

When I upgraded my project to 1.3.3 yesterday using the regular 'grails upgrade' command, everything went well but once I started the app, dependency injection no longer seems to work in my Grails Service classes. I did not change the BlazeDS nor Spring Integration setup.

When I call the exact same Service method from a Grails controller (using 1.3.3), dependancies are injected.

Did anyone had the same problem and know the solution to this?

**Update/temp solution:**

Additional tests point out that services are no longer exposed to BlazeDS when using the @RemotingDestination annotation in Grails 1.3. Adding @Service("someServiceClass"), as stated in the comment below, solved the exposure but broke the grails dependency injection mechanism.

Explicitly defining the remoting-destinations in the flex-servlet.xml 'solves' the problem. Services are exposed and grails stuff works again. Well it´s more a temporary workaround.

```
<flex:remoting-destination ref="serviceName" />
```

Comment: Strange is also that I have to add @Service("someServiceClass") for each service class, otherwise the service is not exposed. With grails 1.2.1 @RemotingDestination was sufficient. Not sure if related...